# Tuning for alpha/lambda using Caret

Tags: r, r-caret, glmnet

My end goal, with data in the matrix below, is training a number of models across a grid of different lambdas and alphas, using the `glmnet` method.  Perhaps there is another way to approach this tuning problem as well.

```
x <- Macro[1:13, 3:21]
x <- as.matrix(x)
y <- Macro[1:13, 2:2]
y <- as.matrix(y)

myfit <- caret::train(x, y,
                  method = "glmnet",
                  tuneGrid = expand.grid(.alpha = seq(.05, 1, length = 15),
                                                     .lambda = c((5:10)/10)))
```

The above code returns the following error:

> Error in train.default(x, y, method = "glmnet", tuneGrid = expand.grid(.alpha = seq(0.05,  : 
>     Metric RMSE not applicable for classification models

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your response variable `y` is a matrix but it should be `"A numeric or factor vector containing the outcome for each sample"` according to the documentation of `train`. Therefore, you just have to remove `y <- as.matrix(y)` from your code and it will work.